# how to extract data from .txt not by specified row and column numbers?

Tags: matlab

I have a *6*-by-*3* matrix as `sample.txt` file such as:

```
 1,0,0.01

 2,1,0.03

 2,0,0.04

 3,1,0.06

 3,2,0.05

 3,3,0.07
```

which columns refers to  `A`, `Z` and `D`  separately.
I want a Matlab code which when I write `A` and `Z` it write `D`.
for example when I write `sample(3,2)` it gives me `0.05` not `0`

[the link of the .txt file of these sample data is here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ru5lor2oz9k0r3/sample.txt?dl=0)

Comment: please put the matrix data as a `code` Tag.

Comment: the link of that .txt data was attached

Comment: use `ismember` on the first two  columns specifying `'rows'`

Comment: @Dan, For `ismember` he needs first to extract all the file...

Comment: @Adiel My interpretation of this incredibly vague question is that the OP is actually asking how to index the data rather than extract it (regardless of what the title implies).

Comment: @sam try [`readcsv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) to extract the data

Comment: Dear Dan & Adiel, Thanks a lot for your help. I have a .txt data file as mentioned above ( for example a 6 by 3 numerical matrix, which each column defines a separate variable as: first column: A, second column: Z , third column: D ). In my calculation I actually need a command which by inserting value of A and Z it gives me value of D. for example in the above question if i write A=3 and Z=2 the command give me D=0.05.   Is it possible?

Comment: @sam your comment is just s duplicate of your question. Once again, do it using `ismember`. So once you have your data in a matrix (by using `readcsv`) lets say called `M` then `M(ismember([3,2],M(:,1:2),'rows'),3)`

Answer (score 1):

Based on Dan's comment, here's one way to do it.

First we load data from file:

```
>> load -ascii sample.txt
>> sample
sample =
    1.0000         0    0.0100
    2.0000    1.0000    0.0300
    2.0000         0    0.0400
    3.0000    2.0000    0.0700
    4.0000    2.0000    0.0600
    4.0000    3.0000    0.0500
```

Next we create an anonymous function for convenience:

```
>> D = @(A,Z) sample(ismember(sample(:,1:2), [A,Z], 'rows'), 3);
```

Now we can access the values as:

```
>> D(2,1)
ans =
    0.0300

>> D(1,0)
ans =
    0.0100

>> D(0,0)
ans =
   Empty matrix: 0-by-1
```

Comment: Dear Armo, Dan, Adiel and Vikrant thanks so much for your help.